# Android AAR library - bundle node_modules

Tags: android, react-native, aar

I am working on an android SDK which uses react-native as the view engine to display the activities. When I build the SDK project, i get a **.aar** file (as expected)

however, it doesn't include the node_modules folder at `$projectDir/node_modules`.

**How do i instruct gradle to embedd the node_modules folder during the build?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Android doesn't support generation of a "fat aar" library. I am currently trying to figure out how to solve the same issue.

Comment: Did you get any way to do that?

Comment: I compiled every dependency to a separate aar and published it to my private maven server and referenced all of them in my build.gradle. It is also possible just to drop AARs into libs folder and reference them locally.